# How to step back during debugging or back to last breakpoint in Pycharm?

Tags: debugging, pycharm

Is it possible that Pycharm 'save' the whole staus at a breakpoint and allow the customer repeat debugging from there?

Occasionally I may need to debug a complicate bug which need ~2 hours to reach the target function. The multi-process code consists of many nested invoking and loops. The narrowing down process is pretty tricky. The first breakpoint is easy to set up. But if the second breakpoint was not set up correctly. Or there was one more clicking on 'step over' button. The debug session may exit since there was error. That is terrible since I may need another two hours to start another debugging. If Pycharm allow me to 'save' the debug status at the first breakpoint and allow me back to there whatever the current session ends or not it will be great helpful.

If I could catch up abnormal result before the session exit, then I need to step back during Pycharm debugging to figure out the issue. I searched and found out that both visual studio and IntelliJ has this ability. 'Jumping to Cursor' in Pycharm looks a similar solution. So far I don't have a chance to verify it by using a complex case.

So in genearal, what is the best strategy to debug those bugs which take long time to reach the starting point but failure point/reason is unclear? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no such feature at the moment. PyCharm allows [Jumping to Cursor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jumping-to-line.html?_ga=2.73595666.1415393307.1575884003-1482900810.1575280275), but it doesn't allow saving the state as you mentioned.
Feel free to submit a feature request about it to PyCharm issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY
Although I imagine this is really complicated task to do.